# dyld: Library not loaded - crash with Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, twitter

I am working through the Stanford CS193 course on iOS/Swift. I did run into a rather technical problem while programming the second Twitter assignment. I was having difficulty running on my device (iPhone 6) although the simulator worked fine. I suspected I needed to upgrade from Xcode 7.2 to Xcode 8 and so I did that. After fixing obvious new errors (e.g. new try implemented on system objects), I still cannot get it to run - it (the simulator) exits with:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/peterwills/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Smashspace-hdbpvcoeyafnkuaqzjqknhkcnful/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Twitter.framework/Twitter
>     Reason: image not found

The culprit is a Twitter framework distributed with the course. I did a clean and rebuild of this framework but it still crashes with this message.

Any suggestions will be very much appreciated.

BTW, I build the framework for a generic iOS device and I am simulating an iPhone 6+. In fact, it crashes for any simulated device. Also, I have searched widely to get help on this (99.9% of the problems I have had are solved with a Google search) but had no luck with this. I believe that is because the error message happens in a variety of unrelated situations. In my case, it was not there in previous versions of Xcode and it is related to the cs193 Twitter framework.

Comment: Make sure that you have the framework linked in `Link binary with libraries` and in `embedded frameworks`

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Sorry to comment so late on this. Actually, I never found a solution for the problem. I still suspect that the framework was. Not useable after the upgrade. I ended up abandoning the code - but not a big deal as I had gotten what I wanted in terms of learning.